# Can a dataclass inherit attributes from a normal Python class?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-dataclasses

I have a legacy class which was used as a data structure. It holds some attributes and some methods (like `from_dict()` and `to_dict()` used in the past). That class also inherits some attributes from a another normal base class.

I wish to move all these attributes to a new `@dataclass` . Can my new `dataclass` inherit all these old attributes from the existing plain class?  But obviously not the methods.

I would like to achieve something similar to this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


class BaseClass1:
    def __init__(
        self,
        id: int,
        type: str,
    ):
        self.id = id
        self.type = type

    def to_dict(self):
        # Dummy code here
        pass

    def from_dict(self):
        # Dummy code here
        pass


class BaseClass2(BaseClass1):
    def __init__(self, speed: float, **kwargs):
        self.speed = speed

        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def to_dict(self):
        # Dummy code here
        pass

    def from_dict(self):
        # Dummy code here
        pass


@dataclass
class NewDataStructure(BaseClass2):
    color: str
    owner: str


if __name__ == "__main__":
    new_data = NewDataStructure(
        color="red", owner="john", speed=23.7, id=345, type="car"
    )

    print(new_data)
```

Comment: What makes you think you can't? Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: how do you instansiate it?

Comment: @martineau yes I tried instantiating it obviously the extra attributes not defined in the dataclass throw an error `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'speed'` for example. I eddited the question with the instanstiation.

Comment: Why do you want inheritance if you don't want the methods of the base class? Sounds like you don't want inheritance at all, and just want to add a couple of new attributes to your data class.

Comment: @Dunes sure if I could add the attributes without inheritance that would be great but I dont want to add them manually they are A LOT of them and also the fields in the old class are still used and sometimes updated too. I dont want to duplicate and rely on someone updating both classes in every change

Comment: There's no easy way to do this without a bunch of meta programming or just using `**kwargs` everywhere. That's a bad idea as it will make it harder for type checkers, linters, IDEs and people to check that the class is being used correctly (eg. right number of args and correct types). Best just to bite the bullet and add the extra fields to the new dataclass. It is just something like `foo: int` per attribute after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use multiple inheritance here with the final class inheriting from both a dataclass and the normal base class. That way you can just forward initialization to bases `__init__` methods and any further change will  be automatically included.

From your example, I would use:

```
@dataclass
class TmpDataStructure():
    color: str
    owner: str

class NewDataStructure(TmpDataStructure, BaseClass2):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**{k: v for k, v in kwargs.items()
                            if k in TmpDataStructure.__match_args__})
        BaseClass2.__init__(self, **{k: v for k, v in kwargs.items()
                                     if k not in TmpDataStructure.__match_args__})
```

You will be able to safely do:

```
new_data = NewDataStructure(
    color="red", owner="john", speed=23.7, id=345, type="car"
)

print(new_data)
```

But you would only get the fields defined in the dataclass:

```
NewDataStructure(color='red', owner='john')
```

And this will also inherit the methods from `BaseClass2` and `BaseClass1`...

Comment: thanks for the reply. This might work but makes thinks ay to messy I might as well not use a dataclass and keep using the old way :-/ There should be a feature like this for dataclasses to help people move form old classes to dataclasses

Comment: @KZiovas: as you were told in comment, there is no simple way to do that. I have just proposed what I thought to be the less *messy* possible... But I agree that it is far from a natural path ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the function parameters for `__init__` in all your regular classes have a type annotation for each param - i.e. such as `id: int` - then the below approach or a modified version of it should hopefully work in your case, to generate an approximate dataclass schema given any number of regular classes that sub-class from one another:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields


class BaseClass1:
    def __init__(
        self,
        id: int,
        type: str,
    ):
        self.id = id
        self.type = type

    def to_dict(self):
        # Dummy code here
        pass

    def from_dict(self):
        # Dummy code here
        pass


class BaseClass2(BaseClass1):
    def __init__(self, speed: float, **kwargs):
        self.speed = speed

        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def to_dict(self):
        # Dummy code here
        pass

    def from_dict(self):
        # Dummy code here
        pass


@dataclass
class NewDataStructure(BaseClass2):
    color: str
    owner: str


dataclass_fields = []
# start from 1: exclude `NewDataStructure` itself
# exclude last at -1: base for all types is `object`
for cls in reversed(NewDataStructure.__mro__[1:-1]):
    init_fn_annotated_params = getattr(cls.__init__, '__annotations__', {})
    if not init_fn_annotated_params:
        continue
    dataclass_fields.append(f'    # generated from `{cls.__qualname__}`')
    for field, ftype in init_fn_annotated_params.items():
        type_name = getattr(ftype, '__qualname__', ftype.__name__)
        dataclass_fields.append(f'    {field}: {type_name}')

# now finally, print out the generated dataclass schema
print('@dataclass')
print('class NewDataStructure(BaseClass2):')
print('\n'.join(dataclass_fields))
print('    # generated from `NewDataStructure`')
for f in fields(NewDataStructure):
    type_name = getattr(f.type, '__qualname__', f.type.__name__)
    print(f'    {f.name}: {type_name}')
```

Output:

```
@dataclass
class NewDataStructure(BaseClass2):
    # generated from `BaseClass1`
    id: int
    type: str
    # generated from `BaseClass2`
    speed: float
    # generated from `NewDataStructure`
    color: str
    owner: str
```